# SVN Rename error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In SVN my folder structure is
Folder1
 |
  -> SubFolder1
        |
         -> SubSubFolder1

I have only access to SubFolder1 and all its sub folders(SubSubFolder1 in my case).
I do not have access to Folder1.
I want to rename the SubFolder1 to NewSubFolder1.
I am using tortoise SVN on win7. I don't get the rename option when i right click on SubFolder1 repository.
I tried to rename through repo browser but I am getting the following error:

> Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method not Allowed) in
>   response to PROPFIND request for '/'

Any idea how I can rename it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

Think of folders in SVN as a textfile containing a list of all sub-items. Then you'll see, that to modify SubFolder1, you need to modify the 'contents' of Folder1.

Renaming is not technically an operation on the item itself, but of the parent.